# SPOJ : Vertex Cover (PT07X) Wrong Answer

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am trying vertex cover problem. Even an imperfect code cleared all the cases on soj judge, but I got one test case (in comments) where it failed, so I tried to remove it. But, now its not accepting. [Problem Link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07X/)

Problem Description: You have to find the vertex cover of a wneighted, undirected tree i.e. to find a vertex set of minimum size in this tree such that each edge has as least one of its end-points in that set.

My Algorithm is based on DFS. Earlier I used a straightforward logic that, do DFS and while backtracking, if child vertex is not included, include its parent (if not already included). And, it got accepted. But, then it failed on a simple case of skewed tree with 6 vertex. The answer should be 2, but it was giving 3. So, I made slight modification.

I added another parameter to check if a vertex is already covered by its parent or its child, and if so, neglect. So, whenever a find a vertex not covered yet, I add it's parent in the vertex set.

My Old Source Code:

```
vector<int> edge[100000]; // to store edges
bool included[100000];    // to keep track of elements in vertex cover set
bool done[100000];        // to keep track of undiscivered nodes to do DFS on tree
int cnt;                  // count the elements in vertex set

/* Function performs DFS and makes a vertex cover set */
bool solve(int source){
  done[source] = true;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<edge[source].size(); ++i){
    if(!done[edge[source][i]]){  // if node is undiscovered
      if(!solve(edge[source][i]) && !included[source]){   // if child node is not included and neither its parent
         included[source] = true;    // element added to vertex cover set
         cnt++;                      // increasing the size of set
      }
    }
  }
  return included[source]; // return the status of current source vertex
}

int main(){
  int n,u,v;
  scanint(n);
  for(int i = 0; i<n-1; ++i){
    done[i] = false;
    included[i] = false;
    scanint(u);
    scanint(v);
    edge[u-1].push_back(v-1);
    edge[v-1].push_back(u-1);
  }
  done[n-1] = false;
  included[n-1] = false;
  cnt = 0;
  solve(0);
  printf("%d\n", cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

My New Source Code:

```
vector<int> edge[100000];   // to store edges
bool incld[100000];         // to keep track of nodes in vertex cover set
bool covrd[100000];         // to keep track of nodes already covered
bool done[100000];          // to keep track of undiscovered nodes to perform DFS
int cnt;                    // keep track of size of vertex cover set

/* Function to calculate vertex cover set via DFS */
void solve(int source){
  int child;   // to store index of child node
  done[source] = true;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<edge[source].size(); ++i){
    if(!done[edge[source][i]]){ // if child node is undiscovered
      child = edge[source][i];  
      if(incld[child])          // if child node is included in vertex set
         covrd[source] = true;  // setting current node to be covered
      else if(!covrd[child] && !incld[source]){ // if child node is not covered and current node is not included in vertex set
         incld[source] = true;     // including current node
         covrd[child] = true;      // covering child node
         cnt++;                    // incrementing size of vertex cover set
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  int n,u,v;
  scanint(n);
  for(int i = 0; i<n-1; ++i){
    done[i] = false;
    incld[i] = false;
    covrd[i] = false;
    scanint(u);
    scanint(v);
    edge[u-1].push_back(v-1);
    edge[v-1].push_back(u-1);
  }
  done[n-1] = false;
  incld[n-1] = false;
  covrd[n-1] = false;
  cnt = 0;
  solve(0);
  printf("%d\n", cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first solution is correct(you can find a proof [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/correctness-proof-of-a-greedy-algorithm-for-minimum-vertex-cover-of-a-tree)). The answer for a skewed tree with 6 vertices is actually 3(the comment in the link which says that the answer is 2 is wrong).